# Extremely inefficient code written in C++

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

The computation time for the following function is very high. Is there any room for improvement?  Should I be accessing the elements of matrix `X` differently? I appreciate any comments or suggestions.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]


arma::mat myfunc(const int& n,
                 const int& p,
                 arma::mat& X,
                 arma::rowvec& y,
                 const arma::rowvec& types,
                 const arma::mat& rat,
                 const arma::rowvec& betas){
  
  arma::mat final(p+p,n);
  final.zeros();
  int i,j;
  
  for(i=0; i < n; ++i){
    arma::colvec finalfirst(p+p); finalfirst.zeros();
    for(j=0; j < n; ++j){
      arma::mat Xt = X * log(y(j));
      arma::mat finalX = join_rows(X,Xt);
      
      arma::rowvec Xi = finalX.row(i);
      
      if(types(i)==1 && y(j)==y(i)){
        finalfirst += (Xi.t() - rat.col(j));
      }
      if(types(i)>1 && y(j) > y(i)){
        finalfirst -= (Xi.t() - rat.col(j)) * exp(arma::as_scalar(betas*Xi.t()));
        
      }
      else if(y(j) <= y(i)){
        finalfirst -= Xi.t() * exp(arma::as_scalar(betas*Xi.t()));
      }
    }
    
    final.col(i) = finalfirst;
  }
  
  return(final);
}




/*** R
m=4000
types = runif(m,0,5)
types[types<=1] = 0 ; types[types > 1 & types < 3] = 1; types[types>=3]=2
microbenchmark(out = myfunc(n=m,p=2,X=matrix(rnorm(m*2),nrow=m,ncol=2),y=runif(m,0,3),types=types,rat=matrix(rnorm(m*4),nrow=4,ncol=m),betas=c(1,2,3,4)))
*/
```

Comment: This might be a better fit at Code Review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on

Comment: everything in the inner loop is calculated n*n times, but `arma::mat Xt = X * log(y(j)); arma::mat finalX = join_rows(X,Xt);` only depends on `j`, I didnt look further but this looks like you can either swap the loops or trade memory for cpu cycles

Comment: It would be beneficial to known what this code supposed to do, the we could know if it is correct and it its time complexity is optimal.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It's attracting downvotes and close votes there while it got answered here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be helpful if you provide at least *some* explanation of what it is you are doing.

First, I recommend breaking up the code into very small chunks, microbenchmarking each chunk, and finding bottleneck operations. This is better than throwing the whole function at the wall all at once.

#### row vs. column access

`join_rows(X,Xt)`

This is a very slow operation, especially because you are adding a `rowvec` to a column-oriented `mat`. Armadillo matrices are stored as a vector in column-major order, so behind the scenes Armadillo is calling `push_back` in *n* non-contiguous locations, where *n* is the number of columns.

It seems you may be able to avoid this altogether, as `finalX.row(i)` is the only call that depends on `finalX` in this loop. Just figure out what `.row(i)` is.

#### implicit operations

You do a lot of transposing, maybe you should be working with a transposed matrix from the get-go?

`Xi.t()` is called twice in the same line:
`finalfirst -= (Xi.t() - rat.col(j)) * exp(arma::as_scalar(betas*Xi.t()));`

Transposing a row vector is pretty pointless, just initialize it as a column vector and iterate through it with a good old-fashioned loop. A little more code isn't always a bad thing, it often makes your intent more explicit too.

#### Copying vs. in-place operations

This is a copy:
`final.col(i) = finalfirst;`

Why not operate in-memory and update `final(_, i)` in-place rather than using a temporary `finalfirst` followed by a deep copy into your target matrix? This is a column, so memory is contiguous and the compiler will be able to optimize the access pattern for you as wonderfully as if you were working on any simple vector.

All said, I haven't fully wrapped my head around what it is exactly that you are doing, but @largest_prime_is_463035818 may be right about switching the `for(i...`) and `for(j...)` loops around. It appears you will be able to pull these two rows out of the nested loop:

```
arma::mat Xt = X * log(y(j));
arma::mat finalX = join_rows(X,Xt);
```

since they do not depend on `i` at all.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider your suggestions.